# a simple looping question

Tags: mysql, loops

```
CREATE DEFINER = `dba`@`xx.xx.xx.3` PROCEDURE `oninjadb`.`TESTLOOPER`()
LANGUAGE SQL
DETERMINISTIC
NO SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN

DECLARE counter INT default 0;


simple_loop: LOOP
SET counter=counter+1;
select counter;
 IF counter=100 THEN
    leave simple_loop;

END IF;
end loop simple_loop;
END
```

Okay a simple loop problem, copied from a google search. The only problem is that the loop won't pass thru  more than once, so the output is 1 and that's it. I know this is a simple loop, but I need to get it so I move on to more complicated problems. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Your procedure is actually running 100 queries.  **The *first* query is returning a result with the number 1.**  The 99 other results sets are returning the correct numbers.

Procedures are able to return multiple result sets from multiple queries.  Your ability to read back those different result sets depends on the API you are using.

Comment: I'm using Navicat Premium and mysql 5.1.39-log. I have attempted to insert / update the 99 other queries into a table with no luck. How do I capture those other 99 queries?

Comment: I am not familiar with Navicat, so I don't know how to help you see all of the result sets the procedure creates.  However: if you run multiple INSERT queries from within your procedure, they should all execute successfully.

Answer (score 1):

this might get you back on track :)

```
drop procedure if exists test_looper;

delimiter #

create procedure test_looper
(
in p_max int unsigned
)
proc_main:begin

declare v_counter int unsigned default 0;

if p_max is null or p_max <= 0 then
    leave proc_main;
end if;

while v_counter < p_max do
    select v_counter;
    set v_counter=v_counter+1;
end while;

end proc_main#

delimiter ;


call test_looper(10);
```

Comment: I modified this just slightly (insert into table) and it worked! thanks for the help.